Allow ability to enable n_distinct() when calculating sub totals and percentages to deal with one to many relationships between categorical variables
I have been trying to create nice-looking two-way tables for an R markdown report using the gtsummary package, analyzing a survey. I have been trying to view the relationship between two survey questions where users can pick multiple answers for one of the questions.
I saved the survey answers in long-form, where multiple answers would just have an extra row with answer combinations for one user_id.
However, I need to have the sub_totals and percentages calculated from the number of unique users to pick each answer. I don't know how to prevent double counting. Is there a way to do this using tbl_summary?
I created some sample R code to explain what I need.
Test <- data.frame(user_id = c("1","1","2","3","3","4","4","4","5", "6"),
           Question1 = c("A","A","B","C","C","A","A","A","A","B"),
           Question2 = c("Side-effect 1", "Side-effect 2", "Side-effect 3", "Side-effect 1", "Side-effect 3", "Side-effect 1", "Side-effect 2", "Side-effect 3", "Side-effect 3", "Side-effect 1"))
           

Test %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = Question1, include = c(Question1, Question2))

Outputting this:
Characteristic  A, N = 6    B, N = 2    C, N = 2
Question2           
    Side-effect 1   2 (33%) 1 (50%) 1 (50%)
    Side-effect 2   2 (33%) 0 (0%)  0 (0%)
    Side-effect 3   2 (33%) 1 (50%) 1 (50%)
1 n (%)

However,
However, the way I need it, the subtotal for "A" should be 3 not 6 because there are three user_ids who selected A, and C's subtotal should be 1 as there is only one user_id which had C. The percentages should change to reflect this as well. It's ok if the A column adds up to more than 100%, because users can pick more than one answer. So I want the output to look like this instead:
Characteristic  A, N = 3    B, N = 2    C, N = 2
Question2           
    Side-effect 1   2 (67%) 1 (50%) 1 (100%)
    Side-effect 2   2 (67%) 0 (0%)  0 (0%)
    Side-effect 3   2 (67%) 1 (50%) 1 (100%)
1 n (%)

Is there a way to count distinct user_id to get sub_totals similar to a Test %>% group_by(Question1) %>% summarize(sub_total = n_disinct(user_id)) Or is there a manual over-ride for sub_totals? I also want to add applicable tests, but that can wait for now.

I don't know how to accomplish that using gtsummary, but you can try to replicate in the hard way, for example
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Test %>% 
  mutate(
    .by = Question1,
    users = n_distinct(user_id),
    Question1 = paste0(Question1," (N = ",users,")") ) %>% 
  summarise(
    .by = c(Question1,Question2),
    n = paste0(n()," (",round(100*n()/users),"%)")
  ) %>%
  unique() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Question1,values_from = n,values_fill = "0 (0%)") 



Yeah, I figured I might just have to do it manually. I just like a lot of the automatic formatting gtsummary does. Thanks for the help.
